# Trying to push large TensorFlow model to GitHub repo using GitHub's Large File Storage

Tags: tensorflow, github, large-files, gitpod

I have a large TensorFlow model that I want to push to a GitHub repo. The file exceeds GitHub's size limit of 100MB.

I am trying to use Git [Large File Storage](https://git-lfs.github.com/), running the following commands:

```
brew install git-lfs

git lfs track "*.zip"

git lfs track "*.json"

git lfs track "*.h5"

git add .gitattributes

git add .

git commit -m 'adding git large file storage'

git push origin master
```

...but I still get the following **error**:

`remote: error: File my_big_model.zip is 235.37 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB remote: error: File tf_model.h5 is 255.54 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com. ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)`

I am running this inside [GitPod](https://www.gitpod.io/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to do

```
git lfs push --all origin master
```

before the `git push origin master`. What you're doing here is, pushing the files to LFS and pushing the pointers to GitHub.
This might be helpful: [Where are git-lfs files stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34181356/where-are-git-lfs-files-stored)

Answer (score 0):

You should first push the .gitattributes to the git server and only then push the large files.